# Catch blank variable int input in java

Tags: java, swing, parseint

I want my code to catch if the user didn't input anything. I can't use ab.equals(null), ab.isEmpty() because I convert the String to integer as you can see.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Mango {


    public static void main (String[] args){

        String ab = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Anything");
        double sum = 0;
        double x = Integer.parseInt(ab);

        if(x <= 0){

            System.out.println("Empty!");

        }else{

            sum+=x; 

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the return value BEFORE you try converting it...

```
String ab = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Anything");
if (ab != null && !ab.trim().isEmpty()) {
    // Try and convert the value...
} else {
    // Bad input
}
```

**Example**

```
double sum = 0;
String ab = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Anything");
if (ab != null && !ab.trim().isEmpty()) {
    double x = Integer.parseInt(ab);
    sum += x;
} else {
    System.out.println("\"" + ab + "\" is not a valid input value");
}
```

Comment: You might need to use try catch as well ?

Comment: @almasshaikh That depends, `NumberFormatException` is a `RuntimeException` and you should avoid using `try-catch` blocks to control logic flow. Not saying you should never do it, you just need to provide the use-case justificaiton for it...

Comment: It's edge cases that OP wants to cover and hence i asked for the same :)

Comment: @almasshaikh This is tre, as I said, you need to make the justification on each case, you could, for example use a regular expression to test for a numeric value before doing the conversion

Answer (score 2):

You have to catch `NumberFormatException`, since that's the exception that would be thrown if you call `parseInt` on an empty String:

```
double x = -1;
try {
    x = Integer.parseInt(ab);
}
catch (NumberFormatException exc) {
    x = -1;
}
```

You can check if the String is empty prior to calling `parseInt`, but then you might still get this exception if the user enters some non-numeric characters or a too large number.

Comment: This is a personal nit pick, so I don't think the answer is "wrong", but you should generally try an avoid using `try-catch` for branching logic

Comment: @MadProgrammer To avoid having to catch the exception entirely, you'll need to implement some of the logic that parseInt already contains - check that all characters of the String are digits, and that the number is not too large (or too small) to fit in an int.

Comment: That's true. Considering `NumberFormatException` is a `RuntimeException`, it also makes it more dangerous to trap it.  As a general rule of thumb, it's unadvisable to use `try-catch` blocks to control program logic, not saying your NEVER should do it, just that's it's unadvisable.  You could equally use a regular expression, for example, to do a quick check on the validity of the `String`